# how to stop suggestions for EditText while entering text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

In my application , i have to submit Username and Password. But, it shows some suggestions while entering data. i am using the following in my xml.

```
<EditText    
        android:id="@+id/edtpass" 
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/login_password_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_bg"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"  
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        />
```

[image]

So, please guide me how to stop suggesstions.

Comment: android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" use this

Comment: or you can use "android:inputType="textFilter" to disable suggestions.

Comment: for Username
Username.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

for password Edit Text Just use:
android:inputType="textPassword"

Comment: i tried both , but its not working in my devices. I am using ASUS device and Samsung tab.

Comment: Hi, did you find solution for this issue? I have the exactly same problem with Asus

Answer (score 0):

In the layout XML, add the following attribute to your `EditText:`

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType

Comment: Thankyou for Answer, but it is not working.

Comment: suggestions are still shown on HTC Desire 2.2 (and probably other HTC Sense devices as well).

Answer (score 0):

In EditText:

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: suggestions are still shown on HTC Desire 2.2 (and probably other HTC Sense devices as well).

Comment: i am Asus Device and Samsung tab. In both devices its not working.